# Равносторонний квадрат, не зная изначально возможную ширину (html/css)?

Tags: html, css

Существует `list`, ширину которого мы не знаем. Как сделать так, чтобы высота `list__item` была равна его ширине?

```css
.list
{
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.list__item
{
  color: white;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list__item">item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: нашел: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537806/css-height-same-as-width?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa . Получается или JS или хак на css

Comment: Да ну какой js. На css элементарно сделать любое соотношение сторон. Работает существенно быстрее js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использовать переменные то можно добиться это, смотрите

```css
:root {
  --num: 150px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.items {
  background: red;
  width: var(--num);
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item {
  color: white;
  background: green;
  width: inherit;
  height: var(--num);
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```